# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid - Incorrect Records Saving Using Read Only

Tags: oracle, grid, oracle-apex, readonly, interactive

I have an interactive grid with 7 columns. Pertinent to this question are the columns: Fund_Title and Need_Ind. Fund_Title is type Display Only. Need_Ind is type Select List. Need_Ind also has a property setting on Read Only of Type = Value, Item = Fund_Title, Value = Reporting Only, Execute = For Each Row. The page displays appropriately. I am able to utilize the select list in Need_Ind on all rows that do not have a value of Reporting Only as the Fund_Title. Only those rows where column Fund_Title = Reporting Only have the cell Need_Ind disabled. It is actually grayed out.  The problem is with the save. Any rows I have modified are being correctly saved. However, any rows with the value Reporting Only in Fund_Title are also being saved, which are the exact rows I do not want to be editable. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't quite understand. How do rows whose FUND_TITLE = 'Reporting Only' come into the Interactive Grid? Are they fetched from the database? If so, they already *are* saved, aren't they? On the other hand, if you manually enter such rows, why do you allow 'Reporting Only' to be entered if you don't want to save such records? Finally, you might need to write your own process for saving records into the table, deciding which values are OK and which are not. I'd suggest you not do come to that stage, it might be a tedious job.

Comment: Fund_Title is retrieved from the database and is display only in the grid. You are correct I do not want to try to write my own save process.